# MTLS certificate authentication of integration request from AWS Apigateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, api-gateway, mtls

I need to configure my spring boot app to only accept requests from our API gateway aws service, to do that I need to set up MTLS certificate authentication.

One of the best tutorials I found on this topic is https://github.com/andifalk/client-certificate-demo.

As far as I understand I need to create a keystore.p12 file, generate a public certificate, and then add it to the trust store to be able to authenticate the user using this certificate later.

The problem is - that I should use the ready certificate prepared by Api gateway, I can't find any option to somehow upload my self-signed cert to AWS and use it, the only thing I can do is download the .cer file from the AWS console and set up my app auth basing on it.

I was trying to into an existing key pair inside the keystore and I was getting an error

[image]

'The chosen certificate was not used to sign the last certificate in the certificate chain', when I am trying to remove the generated certificate to replace it with the one generated by AWS I also get an error

[image]

I can't find any info on the internet on how to generate key pairs using existing .cer.

If someone had some experience with configuring mtls auth for integrational requests from the aws api gateway please help.